# Advice on a Distributable client for message publication

Tags: java, rabbitmq, distributed-computing, amqp

I need some advice on the best way to implement a software that I need to distribute and install on both windows and linux machines.

I have written a small Java messaging application that runs locally on my machine and listens to a particular port for streaming messages. This application pushes the messages onto a JMS queue.  My web application then polls the JMS queue (also local) and runs as expected.

I now wish to scale my application significantly. This means I want to be able to distribute a messaging application to other users (potentially anywhere in the world) who can install it then select a port number using a simple user interface and then run the application. This application would perform the same as the messaging application I have written in JAVA. It would process messages on the selected port and then publish them to a queue on my queue server - from which my Java Application would poll the messages.

I am wondering a couple of things...

1. I am a Java programmer but wonder what would be the easiest way to produce the remote client that can be easily installed on various platforms? I would rather people could download and install rather than dealing with complex platform dependencies. This might mean a Windows installer...
2. I was thinking of using the AMQP messaging as the backbone - such as RabbitMQ. This is especially important if I decide to shy away from distributing a Java based message application.

Just some thoughts on the approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what would be the easiest way to produce the remote client that can be easily installed on various platforms?

Pure Java, with a GUI, deployed using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The user clicks a link, follows the prompts, and the app. is on screen (with automatic update).

Designed by Sun (maintained by Oracle) to be used on Windows, *nix & OS X.

Comment: The cross-platform leverage is excellent; on Mac OS X, we can disable Java in the browser for security, while still running trusted applications from a web page.

Comment: @trashgod  I cringe whenever I hear "Must work on both.." no matter which 2 OS' are mentioned.  Java is widely usable, so why limit your user base to *just 2* OS variants?

Comment: Agreed. Supported Linux platforms are easy to test using a virtual machine. I only cringe when I hear "Must work on both, including the quirky widget favored by the customer's insistent relative."